# Can you deploy a message driven bean packaged as a EJB JAR on Weblogic?

Tags: ejb, weblogic

Hi I am new to Weblogic and I am trying to figure out how to deploy a MDB properly. I have an EAR project that contains my Beans and config files, am I able to export that as a JAR and deploy that onto the Weblogic server?

Answer (score 0):

EJB's can be deployed as JARs (see oracle [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13702/deployunits.htm) section "Using Archived Files")
and the jar should contain the deployment descriptor xml / Annotations (e.g. @MessageDriven ) that configures the MDB.